# WhatsApp keyboard smiley bug

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, whatsapp-messenger, gboard

I type with keyboard and after typing I want to add a smiley.
Then it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

bit annoying and only since some days

any idea to fix this?

*EDIT:*
also: menu key on i9300 shows menu up the keyboard
and if I click on the red underlined text (& this is directly up the keyboard) the correction drop down is under the keyboard overlay

**Galaxy S 3 [i9300]

PAC ROM newest nightly**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: sorry, already edited

Comment: well, i think it was a ROM bug